# iOS 9 safari webkit crash only on iPad (iPhone works fine)

Tags: javascript, ios, css, ipad, webkit

I have a web app using python/django back end and uses a decent amount of CSS3 animation, and heavy javascript on the front end. This issue is driving me a bit nuts so i just wanted to see if anybody had any ideas on this.

The site crashes webkit on iPad mini running iOS 9.2.  Both safari and chrome crash.  Safari provides the following notice:

```
A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded
```

The crash occurs just after the content shows up before touching anything.  Sometimes it will reload until:

```
A problem repeatedly occurred on ...
```

Other times it will eventually load the page and then after scrolling the page it crashes.  On some rare instances the site will work after clearing the browser cache.

It works perfectly on these devices:

- iPhone 3 iOS 7
- iPhone 4 iOS 7
- iPhone 5 iOS 9.2
- iPhone 6 iOS 9.2
- android
- windows mobile
- all Windows and Mac desktops Chrome, Safari, IE, Firefox

There are no apparent memory leaks as shown in the timeline which includes page load and scrolling through the site content which adds javascript objects and elements to the dom dynamically:
[image: Page load and scrolling through site]

General procedure causing the issue:

- Collect existing DOM elements containing an element with a css backgound-image:url()
- Remove existing elements from DOM.
- Then insert the elements back into the DOM in a new container element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe i found the bug...

Aparently Safari 9 (iPad only) does not like it when you apply css `transform:translate3d();` on an element containing a css `background-image:url(),` with a `z-index:-1;`

- Removing the translate3d improved the issue, but performance was
  horrible and still got random crashes.
- Removing the background-image solved the issue completely, but was a
  requirement.
- Finally, i was able to keep the backgound-image and the translate3d
  as long as i removed the z-index.

So in short, if you are getting consistent crashes in Safari 9 on ipad only then try and remove all negative z-index's and see if that fixes it.